# Have encdoing problems only in static generated page Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i'm working on that problem 2 days already.

*Nuxt version **^1.4.0***

When you visiting [that page](https://ivfdv.ru/services/cervix/) there are encoding problems, as you can see I have those symbols on page load [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxFb.png), after page loads, text is shown as [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLJJu.png), but title still has encoding [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zUFV.png) and [meta tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSqyi.png).

I'm using static generation (nuxt generate), in SSR mode everything is [OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zYcH.png).

**Here is my code:**

```
import PageHeader from "~/components/PageHeader.vue";
import DoctorCard from "~/components/DoctorCard.vue";
import PageContent from "~/components/PageContent.vue";
import GridBlock from "~/components/GridBlock.vue";
import GridItem from "~/components/GridBlockItem.vue";
import SidebarWidget from "~/components/SidebarWidget.vue";
import FileLink from "~/components/FileLink";

import doctors from "~/assets/doctors";

const pageTitle = "Наши врачи";

export default {
  name: "Doctors",
  components: {
    PageHeader,
    DoctorCard,
    PageContent,
    GridBlock,
    GridItem,
    SidebarWidget,
    FileLink
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: pageTitle,
      doctors: doctors
    };
  },
  head: {
    title:
      "Врачи и сотрудники клиники женского здоровья «Святая Мария» во Владивостоке",
    meta: [
      {
        description:
          "Врачи и сотрудники центра «Святая Мария» - имеют профильное образование и многолетний опыт медицинской практики. Врачи центра «Святая Мария» будут рады помочь.",
        keywords:
          "врачи центра эко, сотрудники центра эко, специалисты центра эко"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**For example another page:**

```
import PageHeader from "~/components/PageHeader.vue";
import PageContent from "~/components/PageContent.vue";
import siteConfig from "~/config/siteConfig";
import SidebarWidget from "~/components/SidebarWidget.vue";
import ImageSlider from "~/components/ImageSlider.vue";
import WidgetLinks from "~/components/WidgetLinks.vue";
import FileLink from "~/components/FileLink.vue";
import ContactPhone from "~/components/ContactPhone.vue";

const IMAGES = [
  "about/clinic_1.jpg",
  "about/clinic_2.jpg",
  "about/clinic_3.jpg",
  "about/clinic_4.jpg"
];

export default {
  name: "about_page",
  components: {
    PageHeader,
    PageContent,
    SidebarWidget,
    ImageSlider,
    WidgetLinks,
    FileLink,
    ContactPhone
  },
  head: {
    title: "Информация о клинике «Святая Мария» во Владивостоке",
    meta: [
      {
        description:
          "Центр ЭКО и эндоскопической хирургии во Владивостоке. Осуществляем диагностику и лечение гинекологических заболеваний, бесплодия.",
        keywords:
          "центр эко, эндоскопическая хирургия, лечение гинекологических заболеваний, лечение бесплодия"
      }
    ]
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "О клинике женского здоровья «Святая Мария»",
      email: siteConfig.email,
      workHours: siteConfig.work_hours,
      images: IMAGES,
      links: [
        {
          title: "Наши врачи",
          path: "/doctors"
        },
        {
          title: "График приема врачей",
          path: "/services/diagnostic/consultation"
        },
        {
          title: "Вакансии",
          path: "/jobs"
        },
        {
          title: "Сотрудничество",
          path: "/cooperation"
        },
        {
          title: "Лицензии",
          path: "/documents"
        },
        {
          title: "Услуги",
          path: "/services"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

As you can see head is same, thanks for any solutions.

Comment: try with `meta: [ { charset: 'utf-8' } ]` in your `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: @Deda, nuxt.js has it by dafault in config

Comment: update to nuxt 2.8